# Convert Date into nvarchar?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I am trying to create a unique value feild which will hold the current ID, and the current date. @QuoteNumber is the unique field i want to create.

So far i think im on the right track but i'm getting an error when trying to add the date into my nvarchar.

```
DECLARE @QuoteNumber nvarchar(50) 
DECLARE @Date varchar(10)
SELECT @Date = (LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 120), 10))
SET @QuoteNumber = 'QU-' + @Date + '-' + SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Edit

---

Iv also tried:

```
SET @Date = CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE(), 20)
```

Comment: You should probably add a tag for the database you're working with.  'oracle', 'sqlserver', 'mysql', etc...

Comment: @Pomster: You need to add `convert(varchar,SCOPE_IDENTITY())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @QuoteNumber nvarchar(50) 
DECLARE @Date varchar(10)
SELECT @Date =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),121)
SET @QuoteNumber = 'QU-' + @Date + '-' + CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Its not date which is causing issue it is `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function which returns INT data and you are trying to concatenate Int value with a string. Because INT is a data type with higher presidence sql server tries to convert the string to INT and fails and you get the error you get.

Comment: I got this error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'QuoteNumber

Comment: It means Your column QuoteNumber doesnt allow nulls and you are trying to insert a null value. It has nothing to do with the query above. check rest of the code.

Comment: i think my Scope_Identity() is returning null

Comment: well I would use a variable to store the value being returned from Scope_Identity() as soon as I have inserted the records and then use that variable to manipulate other data and stuff. in your code declare an INT variale and d something like `SET @NewID = Scope_Identity()`; and then use that variable on other places.

Comment: You can use `coalesce(somethingThatIsNull, '')` to output an empty string if `somethingThatIsNull` is null. If it is not null it will output the next parameter, '' in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it like this:

```
SELECT @Date = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120);
```

You should always use a length with `varchar()`, although that doesn't affect this query.

Then, `scope_identity()` returns a number, so you need to conver that:

```
SET @QuoteNumber = 'QU-' + @Date + '-' + cast(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as varchar(255);
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the date.  It is because `scope_identity()` returns a number.

Answer (score 1):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is causing that error. You need to cast it to an `varchar` as well.